# Как сделать так, чтобы картинка повернулась на 360, но потом не возвращалась?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, анимация

Нужно сделать так, чтобы картинка повернулась на 360 градусов если на неё навестить, но при этом чтобы она не возвращалась в изначальное положение. [Тут пример кода](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230062/523186), где изображение поворачивается и возвращается, как раз таки возврат в изначальное положение и надо предотвратить.

Answer (score 0):

```
.social {
    margin-right:10px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
}

.social:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
```

Сам догадался, спасибо:)

Answer (score -1):

Вроде бы это можно сделать только в JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  e.target.style.transform = 'rotate(360deg)'
})
```

```css
img {
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg" />
```

### Объяснение:

Изображение добавляем слушателя события `mouseenter`, ему (изображению) же в стили при срабатывании события добавляем `transition: rotate(360deg)` и т.к. стили уже добавлены, они не меняются, соответственно повторного переворота не случается.

Comment: Большое спасибо, уже разобрался!)